# Implementing async timeout using poor mans async/await constructs in .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, timeout, pattern-matching, task-parallel-library, async-await

## Motivation

C# 5.0 async/await constructs are awesome, unfortunately yet Microsoft only shown a release candidate of both .NET 4.5 and VS 2012, and it will take some time until these technologies will get widely adopted in our projects.

In Stephen Toub's [Asynchronous methods, C# iterators, and Tasks](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/30/9809774.aspx) I've found a replacement that can be nicely used in .NET 4.0. There are also a dozen of other implementations that make it possible using the approach even in .NET 2.0 though they seem little outdated and less feature-rich.

## Example

So now my .NET 4.0 code looks like (the commented sections show how it is done in .NET 4.5):

```
//private async Task ProcessMessageAsync()
private IEnumerable<Task> ProcessMessageAsync()
{
    //var udpReceiveResult = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();

    var task = Task<UdpAsyncReceiveResult>
               .Factory
               .FromAsync(udpClient.BeginReceive, udpClient.EndReceive, null);

    yield return task;

    var udpReceiveResult = task.Result;

    //... blah blah blah

    if (message is BootstrapRequest)
    {
        var typedMessage = ((BootstrapRequest)(message));

        // !!! .NET 4.0 has no overload for CancellationTokenSource that 
        // !!! takes timeout parameter :(
        var cts 
          = new CancellationTokenSource(BootstrapResponseTimeout); // Error here

        //... blah blah blah

        // Say(messageIPEndPoint, responseMessage, cts.Token);

        Task.Factory.Iterate(Say(messageIPEndPoint, responseMessage, cts.Token));
    }
}
```

Looks little ugly though it does the job

## The question

When using [CancellationTokenSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) in .NET 4.5 there is a constructor that takes timespan as a timeout parameter, so that resulting `CancellationTokenSource` cancels within specified period of time.
.Net 4.0 is not able to timeout, so what is the correct way of doing that in .Net 4.0?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4

Comment: Changed "timer" to "timeout" in the title since the question is about timeout and "timer" (used for recurring with some period executions) was misleading and disorienting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this really have anything to do with async/await?  Looks like you're just needing a way to cancel the token, independently of async/await, right?  In that case, could you simply create a Timer that calls Cancel after the timeout?

```
new Timer(state => cts.Cancel(), null, BootstrapResponseTimeout, Timeout.Infinite);
```

**EDIT**

My initial response above is the basic idea, but a more robust solution is can be found in [Is CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter() leaky?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715688/is-cancellationtokensource-cancelafter-leaky) (actually the .Net 4.5 implementation of the constructor you're seeking).  Here's a function you can use to create timeout tokens based on that code.

```
public static CancellationTokenSource CreateTimeoutToken(int dueTime) {
    if (dueTime < -1) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dueTime");
    }
    var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var timer = new Timer(self => {
        ((Timer)self).Dispose();
        try {
            source.Cancel();
        } catch (ObjectDisposedException) {}
    });
    timer.Change(dueTime, -1);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: What kind of timer you propose to use Dax?

Comment: `System.Threading.Timer` is what I was thinking, but I'd imagine any of them should work--I'm not an expert on the differences between the various kinds of .Net `Timer`s.

Comment: But it will block the thread and we'll start loosing all the benefits of asynchronous approach... :(

Comment: It shouldn't block anything; you're thinking of Thread.Sleep()?  Timer will just grab a new thread from the thread pool and run on it each time the timer is triggered.  Should be very low overhead.

Comment: Ok I see, but then how many threads would it require to wait for 10-20 simultaneous operations in the background? I have these timeouts widely used in my code...

Comment: If they're truly simultaneous, you should be able to reuse the same cts token on all those calls, right?  And even if not, all the thread does is call cts.Cancel() and exit--so unless you're calling them microseconds apart, it's unlikely to ever need more than one thread at a time.

Comment: @Lu4 Actually you can see the code for the .Net 4.5 `CancellationTokenSource.CancelAfter` method, which is called by the `TimeSpan` constructor here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715688/is-cancellationtokensource-cancelafter-leaky.  Same basic idea as the above; should be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, you can use async/await in 4.0 projects, just use [the async targeting pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/04/26/async-targeting-pack-for-visual-studio-11-now-available-for-net-4-and-silverlight-5-greg.aspx).  Works Great For Me!

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `CancelAfter()`, which is an extension method in `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` which is very similar to accepted answer above.

This is the refereance souce code when I press F12 to see the implementation of `CancelAfter()`:

```
  /// <summary>Cancels the <see cref="T:System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource" /> after the specified duration.</summary>
  /// <param name="source">The CancellationTokenSource.</param>
  /// <param name="dueTime">The due time in milliseconds for the source to be canceled.</param>
  public static void CancelAfter(this CancellationTokenSource source, int dueTime)
  {
    if (source == null)
      throw new NullReferenceException();
    if (dueTime < -1)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("dueTime");
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    Timer timer = (Timer) null;
    timer = new Timer((TimerCallback) (state =>
    {
      timer.Dispose();
      TimerManager.Remove(timer);
      try
      {
        source.Cancel();
      }
      catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
      {
      }
    }), (object) null, -1, -1);
    TimerManager.Add(timer);
    timer.Change(dueTime, -1);
  }
```