# how can I make the httprequest stop if internet is slow and data is not gather within 10 seconds?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I get crashes when I work with my app with a slow internet when I keep pressing different buttons that gathers data via httprequests. how could i make a function so that if i do not recieve the data within for example 10 seconds, the attempt to gather the data from the httprequest should be cancelled.

This is my code:

```
static public async Task<JObject> getCategories ()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();
        try {
        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost");
        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

        var jsonResult = JObject.Parse (resultString);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (resultString);

        return jsonResult;
    }

        catch {

            return null;
        }

    }



async void createCategory (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
var getCategory = await parseAPI.getCategories ();

if (getCategory != null) {

foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) {
    id = currentItem ["ID"].ToString ();
    objectid = currentItem ["objectid"].ToString ();

    //connected
    }

  }
        } else {

            //no connection

        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx) which has a  method provided in it which is [`CancelAfter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194678(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 var token = new CancellationTokenSource();
 token.CancelAfter(10000); // after 10 secs
 var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost",token.Token);
 var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
```

Here is a article about [using Cancellation with GetAsync](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2012/12/07/await-httpclient-getstringasync-and-cancellation/) which you may be interested to read.

Comment: I cannot find "CancellationTokenSource"

Comment: I cannot find GetStringAsync

Comment: var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost",token);, It does not let me add token after the http

Comment: try changing : ``httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost",token);`` to : ``httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost",token.Token);``

Comment: Code runs but does not cancell the request after (in my case) 1 second.

Comment: take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715688/is-cancellationtokensource-cancelafter-leaky

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the timeout on the [httpclient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.118).aspx).

```
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient();
        httpClientRequest.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync("http://localhost");
```

Comment: should I use the timeout inside the try function?

Comment: Yes of course! It will trigger a TaskCanceledException.

Comment: Seems like it doesnt work. I made it 1 second just to try it out. And it does not reach the else (//no connection) code after 1 second.

Comment: is the result coming back with something else than null ? You should add a GetAsync ("http://localhost").ConfigureAwait(false) to your Async calls to avoid capturing the current context

Comment: It returns a result but it takes 5 seconds (for my slow wifi) to recieve it and I have put the timeout to 1 second, so it shouldnt even get a result